# how to initialize data of newly added column at app startup? ~ Java, SpringBoot, DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

have a question about the data initialization of newly added columns on some tables in the case of the SpringBoot app

our team would like to add a new column to the existing table

& after we ran the table schema migration,
all the data in the newly added column are NULL

then, we'd like to set data, referencing another column,
that means I wonder if there is some way to run SQL update statements at the SpringBooot app's start-up like table schema can be updated at the same timing with Flyway

is it possible? & if so, can anyone introduce some article about this into me?

What did you try: I'M not a member of implementation, so I'M in the middle of research

what were you expecting?: data of newly added column can be set at app's startup

Comment: that is exactly what `Flyway` is supposed to do.

Comment: @Andrey B. Panfilov which page should I look at in Flyway document in order to refer to what I want to know?